# Get the current user of a File using C#

Tags: c#

I'm building an application that is run by multiple users on the same network, the users share a folder on a server, any of the users can access the folder and its contents through the application i.e. not through windows explorer.

the problem is that when a user wants to open a file that is already open by another user, I need to get the name of the current file user to notify the new user on who's using the file now.

the files types can vary, nothing specific

is there a way in C# .Net to get the name or the PC ID of the current file user?

Comment: One option is to have your client software create a (delete-on-close) file containing whatever information you want and keep it open alongside the active file.

Comment: I'm not sure I can get the file is "closed" for all types of files

Comment: Microsoft Access creates a lock file (new versions call it `.laccdb`) which contains the necessary information for locking the database to one user. The entire Microsoft Access driver is built to *not* open a file if there is a matching `.laccdb` file in the directory. You would have to, as @AlexK. states, manage this file yourself and delete it when necessary, but it wouldn't be difficult.

Comment: So you pass off the file to a different process?  If that process does not apply any type of locking itself then there is no simple way to know the lock state of the file.

Comment: the application provides an alternate window to show the files, instead of the windows explorer, the file opening itself is simply as follows
       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@Path);
the app cannot hold any information about the opened file status after that

Comment: thank you @AlexK.  for the tip, I took your advice and created a temporary file holding the information I need about the opened file and the user, then waited for the Process.Exited event at which the temporary file is removed.

Comment: thank you @EBrown for the elaboration. it really helps!